# Why does IE fail to server my CSV file from Response.Write?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, header, download, content-type

I've recently developed a web user control that lists a series of reports. When the user clicks on the report it serves back a CSV file download in the response stream using the following code:

```
 Response.Clear();

 Response.ContentType = "text/CSV";

 Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
 Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
 Response.Expires = -1;

 Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "must-revalidate");
 Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate");
 Response.AddHeader("Accept-Header", csvResults.Length.ToString());
 Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", csvResults.Length.ToString());
 Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=test.csv");
 Response.Write(csvResults.ToString());
 Response.Flush();
 Response.End();
```

The code initially worked fine in all browsers. Then the client put a requirement to use SSL for the site. As part of this I introduced a global handler to update the protocol from HTTP to HTTPS for all requests as follows:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string requestURL = Request.Url.ToString().ToLower();
        if (requestURL.StartsWith("http://"))
        {
            Response.Redirect(requestURL.Replace("http:", "https:"));
        }
    }
```

However, since securing the site using SSL the CSV file downloads no longer work for IE although they do continue to work for Firefox / Chrome / Safari.

Is there something I am missing in the headers that is unique to IE in order for the file response to work correctly?

The message I receive from IE is:

> "Internet Explorer cannot download
>   Reports.aspx from .... in ......
>
> Internet Explorer was unable to open
>   this Internet site. The requested site
>   is either unavailable or cannot be
>   found. Please try again later."

UPDATE:

Here is some example fiddler output coming back from the page request which looks like it's serving correctly. Why doesn't IE understand that it's just been served a file?

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 09 Nov 2010 14:23:50 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Pragma: no-cache
Pragma: must-revalidate

content-disposition: attachment; filename="test.csv"
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Content-Length: <length value would be here>
Content-Type: text/CSV

"COL1","COL2","COL3"
"VAL1","VAL2","VAL3"
"VAL1","VAL2","VAL3"
"VAL1","VAL2","VAL3"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After spending hours trying to resolve this I've finally came up with a solution.

Luckily I managed to come across [a post by Eric Law](https://web.archive.org/web/20160201040009/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/10/02/internet-explorer-cannot-download-over-https-when-no-cache.aspx) regarding IE's incompatibility between HTTPS and response headers containing cache directives.

Having now made sure that all response headers were cleared and that no caching instructions were being performed on the response then the file started responding as a download again.

Answer (score 2):

As Brian said, [Eric Law](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/10/02/internet-explorer-cannot-download-over-https-when-no-cache.aspx)'s post is the key to solve this mystery...

the quick solution is:

```
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache");
```

(with the unexplainable fact that 'no-store' must be **before** 'no-cache')

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will fix your problem, but I would double check that the request for the csv file is made with https initially, to avoid going through the redirect in Application_BeginRequest.

You could use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see all the requests being made, which would tell you if you're hitting the redirect code or not.

Comment: The page is definetely HTTPS before the request is launched, fiddler confirmed.

Comment: Hmmm.  What does the url look like when clicking on the report?  Is it a relative path to the page that serves the csv file?

Comment: It's the same page that serves back the response. There is a link per report and when the user clicks the link the first example code block above is executed with the correct csv data being present in the csvResults variable.

Answer (score 0):

With IIS 7.5+ use the [URL Rewrite extention](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) to add an outbound rule to strip off the "no-store" value in the Cache-Control header, and to strip the Pragma header (which is never needed). This rule set would do the trick:

```
<outboundRules>
    <rule name="Always Remove Pragma Header">
        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Pragma" pattern="(.*)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Remove No-Store for Attachments">
        <conditions>
            <add input="{RESPONSE_Content-Disposition}" pattern="attachment" />
        </conditions>
        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Cache-Control" pattern="no-store" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="max-age=0" />
    </rule>
</outboundRules>
```